# Unable to use Expect to interact with windows executable from WSL

Tags: linux, windows, shell, expect, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to automate some interactions with a windows executable (I believe it is a python script that has been packaged up with py2exe or similar) using Expect from within Windows Subsystem for Linux (V1, Debian). If I manually run the executable in WSL, it prints some text that I want to match in Expect. However, if I spawn it with Expect, instead of returning any intelligible text it returns `^[[66;1R`, which looks maybe like some sort of ANSI escape code to me?

This is my MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
set timeout 10
spawn binary-to-automate.exe
exp_internal 1
expect "*Please enter*"
puts $expect_out(buffer)
```

which returns

```
spawn ./binary-to-automate.exe

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*Please enter*"? no

expect: does "\u001b[6n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*Please enter*"? no
^[[66;1Rexpect: timed out
can't read "expect_out(buffer)": no such variable
    while executing
"puts $expect_out(buffer)"
    (file "./test" line 7)
```

Using a dummy shell script in place of the windows binary that just echos text works as expected, any suggestions where I might go from here?

Comment: I think the _ESC 6n_ which you see in the output, asks the terminal to report the cursor position, and now waits for an answer. Using expect to control an application which wants to play with the terminal is tricky, to say the least. What surprises me more, is, that `expect_out(buffer)` does not exist. After all, you have issued the command _expect_, and even if the variable were empty, it should at least exist.